# Find mising numbers from a sequence 1,4,?,16,?,36,?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Please help me find the number absent in the line for the follow sequence $1,4,?,16,?,36,?$. For example I know the absent number in the sequence $5,0,-5,\_,\_,$, they are $-15,-20$.

But I didn't now how to find number in the above sequence. Help me.

Answer (score 2):

$1^2, 2^2, x^2, 4^2, y^2, 6^2, z^2$. Do you see the pattern? $x,y,z$ must be $3, 5, 7$, so the missing terms are $9, 25, 49$.

Answer (score 1):

A "sequence of numbers" can have *any number* so what you are asking is "what numbers would fit a simple pattern here".  Did you notice that all numbers given are **squares**?

Comment: How think sur can explaing please

Comment: A "sequence" doesn't actually have to have any rules or explanation.  Technically a "sequence" simply can be any set of numbers presented one after the other.  So technically the answer can be anything at all from a formal mathematical point of view.  However this is a puzzle point of view where it's assumed that a "sequence" has a pattern or rule.  So it's not your fault, really.  But it is a technicality that drives mathematicians crazy because we don't like people misusing precise and well-defined terms.

Comment: There isn't really any way to solve this except by insight or trying things.  When you do a lot of problems involving squaring things it becomes almost second nature to notice when all the numbers in sequence are squares. It's hard to explain why it will seem obvious to some but not to others.